# Editing border of one side in a cell without CSS, only with HTML/XHTML?

Tags: html

Say I have a table that looks like this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_collapse

Is it possible to remove/edit cells of a border without CSS, and only using HTML/XHTML?

For example, in '50', can I remove the right border of that row only?

Comment: Without CSS you can't.

Comment: Why one should want to do that?

Comment: This is for a little project I'm working on without using CSS, and I came across a problem where it wasn't possible to edit the cells to have specific borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer revolves around [section 11.3.1 of the HTML401 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.1); this uses data which isn't present in the HTML5 specification**.

HTML offers some support for borders through the `frame` and `rules` attributes. These affect entire columns or rows, but not individual cells. You cannot use these to apply a border to only one cell, but you can use this to apply a border to a row or column.

For example, setting `frame="rhs"` (right hand side) and `rules="all"` on the `table` element will render the border like this ([JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkurg/)):

```
1      | 2      | 3      |
       |        |        |
```

#### Values the `frame` attribute supports:

```
void: No sides. This is the default value.
above: The top side only.
below: The bottom side only.
hsides: The top and bottom sides only.
vsides: The right and left sides only.
lhs: The left-hand side only.
rhs: The right-hand side only.
box: All four sides.
border: All four sides.
```

#### Values the `rules` attribute supports:

```
none: No rules. This is the default value.
groups: Rules will appear between row groups...
rows: Rules will appear between rows only.
cols: Rules will appear between columns only.
all: Rules will appear between all rows and columns.
```