# Continuous right border for selected cells only

Tags: html, css, css-tables, cells

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877001/editing-border-of-one-side-in-a-cell-without-css-only-with-html-xhtml)

The above question is similar. But I wanted to know if the right borders can be made continuous?

How do I get the gaps between the vertical lines to disappear and make it look like a continuous line?
Also, I have to use inline CSS styling. Can't work with external CSS or style tags within head either.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking because in your question you've asked _"How do I get the gaps between the vertical lines to disappear and make it look like a continuous line?"_ and [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkurg/) satisfies your need.

Comment: I am having a tough time editing to fit a table in here. I cannot upload a pic yet <lacking required "reputation">

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by doing this

```
   table {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: none;
    border-right: solid 1px #333;
    padding: 10px;
}

tr td:last-of-type {
    border: none;
}
```

[image]

[Click to see working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qpgj6hLr/1/)

Comment: ok, so this seems to use internal css <uses selectors>
Is there a way to do it with inline styling?

Comment: Inline isn't advisable but if you'd like to do that, follow this link to see how you can do that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646928/html-tables-inline-styles